# stay on same page location after passing variables to a php file and executing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I found many examples but I can't figure out how to apply it to my code.  I'm adding a wish list button and want users to click it, get an alert that it was added to their member page and continue scrolling through content.  I know I need to use ajax to send the variables from the url to javascript and then to php with ajax.  But I'm stuck on getting those variables passed to ajax...probably because I'm still learning it.  Using the GET in php is easy to get multiple variables but I can't figure out how to do it in javascript.  And of course I don't want the page to reload.  This is what I'm passing:

```
<div><a href='wish_list.php?title=".urlencode($title)."&link=".urlencode($link)."' 
onClick='wish(this.href); return false;'>Add to Wish List</a></div>
```

How can I set these variables in javascript?  Ajax I would use is:

```
$(function (){
set variables from url
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "wish_list.php",
data: "$link and $title" //Need help with this here
success: function()...
});
});
```

I need the link variable to remain encoded because well it's a link.  So how do I pull the title and link out of url and pass it to the php file?

Answer (score 0):

js can't access php variables. You could store those values in a hidden html input field and then get it with jquery.

```
link = $(#IdHiddenField).val();
```

and then in the ajax function:

```
data: { link: link}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need at least the basics of javascript and jquery to deal with the ajax functions.
You pass the parameters in the data attribute witch is an javascript object. It would look like this:

```
data: {"link":"value of link",  "title":"value of title", "numbers_too":1},
```

You have to replace the values of those attributes above with your server side values.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this data into the  tag using data attributes:

```
<div<a class="sender" data-link="<?= $link; ?>" data-title="<?= $title; ?> href="wish_list.php" ... etc.
```

Then:

```
$(".data").click(function(e){ 
  type: "POST",
  url: $(e).attr("href"),
  data: $(e).data()
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the ajax function to use directy the "href" from link.

```
function wish(link){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: link,
data: '',
success: function()...
});
}
```

With your link:

```
<div><a href='wish_list.php?title=".urlencode($title)."&link=".urlencode($link)."' 
onClick='wish(this.href); return false;'>Add to Wish List</a></div>
```

Then, you get data from url with $_GET.

Comment: I like this idea the best because I know how to get the variables from php.  I got a couple questions...I know they're pretty ignorant but...wish(link) is just the link?  The parameter link is already set or do I have to change something in my div?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><a onClick=wish(urlencode($title),urlencode($link));>Add to Wish List</a></div>

function wish(title,link) {
    $.post("wish_list.php", { title: title, link: link }).done(function() {
        alert("Added to your member page");
    });
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me.  What about the php file?  Like I said before, I understand how to use the $_GET to get the title and link out of the full url...but once {title: title, link: link} are passes, how would I set that into a php variable to be inserted into a db?  Same $_GET?